# How can I find diamonds?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't seem to locate Diamonds in the Pocket Edition of Minecraft, and I've been looking for them for a very long time.

Are there any methods for quickly locating diamonds?

Comment: This is different with every world and this question is too general. It is like, "How do I cook?" or "How do I play games?". Please avoid asking questions that are too general and need a book-long answer.

Comment: @Meraj99 I fail to see a problem here. "Where can I find diamonds?" is hardly general.

Comment: i had the best find on the 6th layer.

Answer (score 6):

The [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Diamond_ore) says you can find diamonds between layers 15 and 0.  The best layers to look for them are from Y=12 to Y=5.  There is an average of 3.097 diamond ore per chunk.

Comment: Downvote, this is a question about Pocket Edition

Comment: @fredley The layers you can find them are still valid.  It may be a  smalller amount per chunk, I'll have to do some research.

Answer (score 3):

- Mark your spawn by digging down one block.
- Staying near the spawn, cut some trees down (you will need at least 25 wood blocks).
- Make lots of wood planks.
- Turn your planks into sticks by putting 2 planks next to each other.
- Make a wooden pickaxe (a shovel is optional).
- Get some coal for torches.
- Go back to spawn.
- Dig down and collect stone for a stone pickaxe (Iron, Gold, Coal, Diamonds, and Lapis may be along sides while digging down, collect them!) until you hit bedrock.
  Remember that diamonds, gold, redstone and lapis lazuli can only be mined with an iron or diamond pickaxe!
- Once you hit bedrock Go back up 11 blocks.
- Make a 10 by 10 room, 3 or 4 blocks high.
- Put torches in room, along with your bed, crafting table, furnace, etc.
- Make long 2 by 2 tunnels branching off room and every 4 blocks mine as far as your pickaxe can go in each direction. This will expose a bigger area and maximise your chance of finding diamonds.
  If you hit a cave, Explore it. Caves are your number 1 priority.
- Keeping each tunnel lit, continue mining until you reach the end of the world
  Eventually you will find diamonds! After you are finished with each tunnel, backtrack, collect the torches, and block off the tunnel.

** RAW MATERIALS NEEDED**:

- 25 wood
- At least 20 coal
- 3 cobblestone for pickaxe
- 8 cobblestone for a Furnace
- 3 wool for a bed (optional)

Comment: My eyes, they bleed.... Please reformat.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja I'm doing the best I can...

Answer (score 1):

For my method, you need the following:

- 64 wood for sticks torches and ladders *3 64 wood oak or spruce
- 64 coal
- 64 coal again for torches
- 20 ladders
- 2*64 torches (coal torches)
- 2*64 sticks
- 10 crafting tables
- 5 beds
- 20 signs
- 25 iron pickaxes
- 10 axes
- 10 swords
- 5 hoes for food
- 5 shovels for dirt gravel and sand

Mine down to bedrock, placing ladders all the way down. Then, place signs up from the first block of bedrock up 16 blocks, one by one. Next, make 3 levels and mine 20 blocks back and make a small 10x10 room. Mine 20 blocks back with 2 blocks in between in all directions and go 20 blocks back on all levels in all directions. Go straight back and don't do mine any more.

If you find lava, put a cobble stone block in it and then make a stairwell up to it and look for diamonds by the lava pool. If you find nothing in the lava, just destroy your stairs and block off the entrance. Use all the torches to light up the mine. Leave at least 3 blocks between torches to so you don't use them all right away. Then just mine like that and place your beds in the levels and your crafting tables.

Use leftover wood for chests to hold all your leftover ladders, torches, and sticks, as well as storage for diamonds.

Alternatively, you can use a radar scanner app that can tell you the precise co-ordinates where you will find diamonds.

Comment: So, in short, your answer is "Dig a branch mine"?

Answer (score 0):

I found diamonds by digging down really deep with an iron pickaxe. I built a really big mine and they were everywhere. This was on survival so watch out for lava.

Comment: There is no lava in the Pocket Edition. Do you mean the PC version?